# when I push image into openshift registry, is it private?

Tags: openshift

When I push Docker image into OpenShift registry, is it private? Looking into About page in my OpenShift console, it says I can push to `registry.rh-us-east-1.openshift.com` registry. When I log in, I can nicely push:

```
oc whoami -t   # to get token
docker login -u <username> -p <token> registry.rh-us-east-1.openshift.com
docker tag xyz registry.rh-us-east-1.openshift.com/xyz/xyz
docker push registry.rh-us-east-1.openshift.com/xyz/xyz
```

And the question is: if I do not share mine username/token with anybody, is the image in that registry private (i.e. can not be accessed by anybody else except for my OpenShift Online account)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, it will only be visible to you as a user when you log into the image registry using `docker login` and to the service accounts in your OpenShift project which need to be able to pull the image from the image registry to deploy it.